# Cannot access CoreData object property

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to set size of cell in collectionView using fetched object's image from coreData.
When I try to access object's property, it is always nil. Data is fault before and after trying to access property. I can set the: `[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];` but it's not the proper way to do.

I try to get image of GalleryItem like this:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize retval;
    NDGGalleryItem* galleryItem2 = [_gallery.allGalleryItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage* image = galleryItem2.image;
    retval.height = image.size.height/5 + 140;
    retval.width = image.size.width/5;

    return retval;
}
```

It's strange that when I put simple iteration trough elements, all the properties have proper values:

```
 for (NDGGalleryItem *galleryItem in _gallery.allGalleryItems) {
        NSLog(@"Name = %@", galleryItem.name);
        image = galleryItem.image;
    }
```

Please, help.

My classes:

GalleryItem

```
@interface NDGGalleryItem : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* tags;

@end
```

GalleryDataManager - the one that makes fetchrequest

```
-(NSArray*)getAllGalleryItems {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NDGGalleryItem"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSError *error;
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
   //[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if ([fetchedObjects count]) {
        return fetchedObjects;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No gallery items found in CoreData");
        ALog(@"%@",error);
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Gallery - stores array _allGalleryItems

```
@interface NDGGallery : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSArray* allGalleryItems;
@property (nonatomic) NDGGalleryDataManager* dataManager;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<NDGGalleryProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar Problem to this.

Your assumptions are correct that the data being fault is not an error and that they should be accessible after accessing the property.

In my case the problem was that i used two contexts. the context where i imported the objects was in this case not the one where i fetched them in these case.

take care that you use the sme context or that you propagate the changes to them by calling save() or force them to refresh by calling refreshObject(, merge: true)